# Is matrix-vector multiplication continuous in infinite-dimensional vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, continuity

Suppose you have a linear map between two (countable) infinite dimensional vector spaces, a matrix $A$ representing this map and an vector $v$ in the appropriate vector space. Is something like $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (A^n \cdot v) = (\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A^n)\cdot v$$

correct, if I know that both limits are actually well-defined?

An argument I tried is something like: "Well both limits actually exist, so on a small neighborhood of $A^n \cdot v$ the matrix $A^n$ is just a bounded linear operator and therefore continous, but that feels kind of circular, since for such a small neighborhood to exist, it needs to be continous.

Comment: I mean this clearly depends on the topology on your infinite dimensional vector space?

Comment: The study of *continuous* linear maps is one of the big things in functional analysis.

Comment: Consider $\ell^2$ and the map $A(x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots) = (0, x_0, x_1, \dots)$. Do your limits converge there? Note that in $\ell^2, \|(x_i)_i\|^2 = \sum_i x_i^2$. Actually, one question you need to ask is "what is $\lim_n A^n$ in the first place? You need to define a topology on the space of operators to take that limit. What topology are you using?

Comment: (1) What is your definition of a matrix representing a map between two infinite dimensional vector spaces? (2) In general with different domain and target raising it to a power does not make sense, or at best depends on some choices.